# Minimize string without losing data

Tags: c#, string

I have a web service. When clients call my webservice, I want to create string expression that specify shortly this service call. For example;

> Caller Username = "xxx" Called Method name = "yyy" Timestamp =
>   "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
>   --and etc.--

I need to store this expression in my own database and also I need to return this to my clients. I have tried compress (GZipStream) and convert to base64 this string. But after that result string length became larger than the original. How can I store this string with reasonable length without losing any data? It is possible minimize it and make meaningful for both side(client and me)?

Comment: Why Base64? You could store it in a binary column..

Comment: Yeah...I would do JSON compressed and stored as binary.

Comment: Also, if you know the format of the string and it's always the same, then you don't need to store "Caller username", "Called method name", etc. Just store the field values, comma separated, and put the field names in when you retrieve/display it.

Comment: Why JSON? If you're going to use binary anyway, you might as well use BSON or protobuf or something more compact.